# How to match a records in progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have store two characters value in two temp table

```
CREATE tt_test1 NO-UNDO
FIELD Value_1 AS CHARACTER.

CREATE  tt_test1.
ASSIGN  tt_test1.Value_1 = "SBCL---DS----A3".

CREATE tt_test2 NO-UNDO
FIELD Value_2 AS CHARACTER.

CREATE tt_test2 NO-UNDO
ASSIGN tt_test2.Value_2 = "4+7+9+14,L-SA".
```

If you see tt_test2.Value_2 is based tt_test1.Value_1.

i.e

4 = L (4th character of  tt_test1.Value_1)

7 = - (7th character of  tt_test1.Value_1)

9 = S (9th character of  tt_test1.Value_1)

14 = A (14th character of  tt_test1.Value_1)

So now my question is how can compare  **tt_test1.Value_1 and  tt_test1.Value_2** is matching correctly?

If its matching then i need to assign in one variable. Please help this case.

Comment: What does this question have to do with “progress-bar” or “progressdialog”?  I feel like I am misunderstanding it somehow.

Comment: I am sorry sir for make a confusion. It wont happen again

Comment: The tags that seem relevant (to me anyway) for this question are "progress-4gl" and "openedge".  Adding unrelated tags just because they happen to contain the word "progress" is counter-productive and confusing.

Comment: Your sample does not compile Unable to understand after -- "CREATE tt_test1". (247). What are you trying to achieve ? From this simple non-compiling sample I guess you're trying to test some relation between two variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SUBSTRING() function to compare the various 4th, 7th, 9th and 14th characters.

Something like:

```
IF SUBSTRING( field1, 4, 1 ) = SUBSTRING( field2, 4, 1) and
   SUBSTRING( field1, 7, 1 ) = SUBSTRING( field2, 7, 1 ) and
   SUBSTRING( field1, 9, 1 ) = SUBSTRING( field2, 9, 1 ) and
   SUBSTRING( field1, 14, 1 ) = SUBSTRING( field2, 14, 1 ) THEN ...
```

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your question.